# Algorithm visualization app/plugin

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I am looking for an application (or and IDE plugin) that I can use in order to test some algorithms I implement.
Mainly metaheuristics used in [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), [VRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem) and other optimization problems.

I have already checked some common suggestions on the net, but they're rather too simple for example [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please elaborate. There is not enough information for me to figure out what you are after.

Comment: Check again. Similar plugin added http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/

Comment: i think you can have a better luck here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this site for exhaustive resources on algorithm visualization

- http://wiki.algoviz.org/AlgovizWiki/

It also depends on what language/toolkits you want to use and plugin. Matplotlip, Gnuplot, Ciro graphics and many many tools can be used.